# Kd-trees .. do you really need to balance before every find()?

Tags: python

The API [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/mathutils.kdtree.html#mathutils.kdtree.KDTree) on `mathutils.kdtree.KDTree` says:

> KDTree.balance **must** have been called before using any of the find
>   methods.

and it also says of `balance()`:

> This builds the entire tree, avoid calling after each insertion.

Is it true that the tree *needs* to be rebuilt before the `find` variants are called? Won't they still work, but less efficiently?

In cases where insertions and subsequent finds are frequent, and you want to avoid rebuilding too often, could you just call `balance()` every now and then to keep the tree in trim?

Comment: For the most part I would have N points, make an N size tree, insert all N items, balance, then use the find methods at will.  Must always balance after a new insert(s)  or an error will be thrown by find.  I think its pretty much:,  insert all first (if possible), then balance then find...

Comment: ... or put more simply find wont work after an insert unless balanced.

Comment: @batFINGER thanks.. I was afraid of that. From what I understand of KDtrees in general, it should be perfectly possible to traverse an unbalanced tree, passing through a sub-optimal number of nodes? I was hoping to insert 1, do a find, insert another, do a find, etc., until I thought: 'time for a tidy-up' and spent the cycles on a rebuild.